# Why is PowerShell copying to a random location?

Tags: powershell

I have the following simple script:

```
$workingDir = "C:\foo\bar"
$projectsDir = "C:\foo"

Copy-Item -Path "$projectsDir\some subpath\MyFile1.dll" -Destination $workingDir
Copy-Item -Path "$projectsDir\somewhere else\MyFile2.dll" -Destination $workingDir
Copy-Item -Path "$projectsDir\another place\MyFile3.dll" -Destination $workingDir
```

For some unknown reason, every time I run this script it copies the files to the correct location (`$workingDir`) ***and also*** copies them to `$projectsDir\some subpath\something\else`. I have to go delete the extra files from the other location every time this script is run.

So far I've tried:

1. changing variable names
2. specifying `-Destination "$workingDir\MyFile1.dll"`
3. using `$null = Copy-Item -Path "...."`
4. I even tried replacing `Copy-Item` with `xcopy.exe`

and nothing changes. I put a breakpoint on the first Copy-Item command and looked at the variables - they all looked right. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted my computer. [Problem solved.](http://youtu.be/nn2FB1P_Mn8)

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting.  I'm trying to figure out what would have caused this.  Either way, congrats on fixing it!

Comment: I suspect that since both xcopy and copy-item had problems, perhaps the problem was something getting mucked up with the way Windows was handling the file system.

Comment: Sounds plausible. Good job fixing it, have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

The only other thing I could think of is to run the `copy-item` like this:

```
Copy-Item -Path $($projectsDir + "\some subpath\MyFile1.dll") -Destination $workingDir
```

This is how I declare almost all of my Variable + SomethingElse scenarios.  Since I haven't scene this behavior, I'll go back and test it some more to see what I can find. If I come up with something else, I redo my answer.

Comment: a more powershelly way to do this is to write: copy-item -path (join-path $projectsDir "some path\myfile1.dll") -dest $dest -- this will figure out trailing/leading slashes etc for you.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about `join-path`.  Thanks for teaching me something new :)